# Dropping marker to new re-centered location in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add a marker when I enter a new address on google-maps. I enter the address, and the map re-centers to the location, but the marker is not displaying at that new location. Am I missing something small in my code?

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document
        .getElementById('autocomplete'));

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, show the place selected
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);
}

function onPlaceChanged() {
    place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);

    } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);  

    }

    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

}
```